# Bad Request (400) error is showing when we enter wrong pin code

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, shopify, pin-code

We are using servisable pin code api provided by our logistic partner at shopify information checkout page.

when pin code is valid(means servisable) then response in json format is perfectly worked but when we enter no servisable(any 6 digit wrong pin code) then showing bad request 400 error.

How to handle this?

Here is my code
code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var from_pincode = 134113;
  $("#checkout_shipping_address_zip").keyup(function() {
    var to_pincode = $('#checkout_shipping_address_zip').val();
    if (to_pincode.length == 6) {
      var zipcodeurl = "https://www.pickrr.com/api/check-pincode-service/?from_pincode=" + from_pincode + "&to_pincode=" + to_pincode + "&auth_token=********";
      $.ajax({
        url: zipcodeurl,
        type: "GET",
        format: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);

        }
      });

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[badrequest screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKpDK.png)

Comment: You should *not* post your private `auth_token` online. I'd suggest you change this ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax `error` handler like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var from_pincode = 134113;
  var to_pincode = 160000;//add 160059 and see the response in case you want
  var zipcodeurl = "https://www.pickrr.com/api/check-pincode-service/?from_pincode=" + from_pincode + "&to_pincode=" + to_pincode + "&auth_token=******";
  $.ajax({
    url: zipcodeurl,
    type: "GET",
    format: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/